# What is jQuery tap event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, tap

The issue is that i should emulate a `tap` event **without** the using of jQuery to call it's handler.
The handler is attached so:

```
$(element).on("tap",".class", handler);
```

I've tried so:

```
event1 = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
event1.initMouseEvent('click', true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, 1, document.body.parentNode);
element.dispatchEvent(event1);
```

and so (also for touchend):

```
event2 = document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
event2.initEvent("touchstart", true, false);
element.dispatchEvent(event2);
```

but it doesn't work.

I am not sure what is inside the wrapper for the `tap` event of jQuery.

Could somebody help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don't you just use `$(element).trigger("tap");`?

Comment: And I'm guessing you're using jQuery mobile, since there's no trace of a "tap" event in normal jQuery. If you look here - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/events/touch.js - you can find the word "tap" to learn more about the "tap" event.